# How to extend a base member field?

Tags: java

I have a class (Base) and a field of type InfoBase holding some information. A
specialization (Ext) of Base needs to hold additional information (InfoExt).
Therefore Ext assigns an InfoExt to Base.info. However I ran into problems when
Base replaces info, since it would assign `info = new InfoBase()` hence the
additional info of InfoExt is lost.

Therefore I created an `abstract void assign()` in Base (variant A). In this
case info needs to be casted to InfoExt everytime it is used in Ext.

In variant B I have thus additionally created `abstract InfoBase info()`.

```
                             variant A                        variant B
+----------------+  +---------------------------+  +----------------------------+
| InfoBase       |  | Base                      |  | Base'                      |
|----------------|  |---------------------------|  |----------------------------|
| + name: String |  | + info: InfoBase          |  | + abstract InfoBase info() |
|                |  | + abstract void assign()  |  | + abstract void assign()   |
|                |  |                           |  |                            |
+----------------+  +---------------------------+  +----------------------------+
          ^                      ^                               ^
          |                      |                               |
          +                      +                               +
+----------------+  +---------------------------+  +----------------------------+
| InfoExt        |  | Ext                       |  | Ext'                       |
|----------------|  |---------------------------|  |----------------------------|
| + id: int      |  | + void assign() {         |  | + InfoExt info             |
|                |  |     info = new InfoExt(); |  | + InfoBase info() {        |
|                |  |   }                       |  |     return info;           |
+----------------+  +---------------------------+  |   }                        |
                                                   | + void assign() {          |
                                                   |     info = new InfoExt();  |
                                                   |   }                        |
                                                   +----------------------------+
```

.

```
 class InfoBase {
   public String name;
 }

 abstract class Base {
    abstract public void assign();
    abstract InfoBase info();
 }


 class InfoExt extends InfoBase {
   public int id;
 }

 class Ext extends Base {
    public InfoExt info;

    @Override InfoBase info() { return info; }

    @Override public void assign() { info = new InfoExt(); }
 }
```

Is this a common situation with a generic way how to deal with it? Are there
any drawbacks to variant A/B?

How can I provide an info field in Base, that subclasses can use to store extended information?

Thank you for your consideration

Comment: I am not sure if understand your problem, you said that the problem is `info` would always needed to be casted, but you didn't solve that problem with either A or B.

Comment: In B: Ext'.info is of type InfoExt, therefore Ext' can access it as InfoExt without a cast (from InfoBase to InfoExt). I hope this clarifies it.

Comment: I think your problem is that you are asking objects for information and not tell them what to do - http://pragprog.com/articles/tell-dont-ask

Comment: Inheritance breaks encapsulation. Mark the superclass `info` as private. If the subclass needs additional information, it can store it in its own field.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this is what you are looking for?

```
abstract class Base {
    private InfoBase info; 

    abstract public void assign();

    protected void setInfo(InfoBase info) {
        this.info = info;
    }

    public InfoBase getInfo() { 
        return info;
    }
}

class Ext extends Base {
    private InfoExt info;

    @Override 
    public InfoExt getInfo() { 
        return info;
    }

    @Override
    public void assign() {
        info = new InfoExt();
        setInfo(info);
    }

}
```

This will allow Base to serve `InfoBase` objects, while Ext can serve `InfoExt`.

Answer (score 0):

if you have one subclass of InfoBase that it's data will be mostly accessed, you should change the type of property 'info' in Base Class to InfoExt.

in the near future, maybe you will have any other subclasses of InfoBase having different data and behaviors, how about you to do that?
in that case, i advise you to use Bridge-Pattern of GOF, it will help you to slove it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a way to avoid casting, this might work (using generics):

```
public abstract class Base<T extends InfoBase> {
    protected T info;

    public T info(){
        return info;
    }

    public abstract void assign();
}


public class ExtBase extends Base<InfoExt> {

    @Override
    public void assign() {
        info = new InfoExt();   
    }
}
```

Info will be of type InfoExt for the subclass ExtBase. Ex)

```
ExtBase b = new ExtBase();
b.info() // Returns Type InfoExt
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your problem, but here goes a tip:

Typically, when instantiating Base subclasses you would have each subclass performing its specific statements in a second method (**initialize**, or something like it) overridden by the subclass. So, for instance, each subclass will instantiate **info** with the specific **InfoBase** subclass.

After that, **Ext** should only override the methods where InfoBase specific behavior is required, casting **info** to the right class.

This is the most simple design. Since I don't know the complexity of your code, I'm not able to give you a more specific solution; but you could also consider using an Adapter Pattern, Strategy or State (depending of the problem to solve, of course).